# How can I subset variables from one column to use in an ANOVA r?

Tags: r, anova

I have the follow test data:

```
df <- data.frame(Type = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D') ,
                 Value = c('4','0','5','5','1','4','4','3','9','1','0','2'))
```

I'd like to run an ANOVA for the interaction between Type "A" and Type "C".

The basic model would look like:

```
aov(Value ~ A * C , data = df)
```

Is there a simple subset function I can use that will only select the values from Type "A" and Type "C"?

Comment: You can use `subset(df, Type %in% c("A", "C"))`. Do you need `aov(Value ~ Type, subset(df, Type %in% c("A", "C")))`

Comment: You may use `broom::tidy` to get the components in a data.frame i.e. `broom::tidy(aov(Value ~ Type, subset(df, Type %in% c("A", "C"))))`

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
broom::tidy(aov(Value ~ Type, subset(df, Type %in% c("A", "C"))))
```